# Curvature /Torsion of space curve on Surface/3-space

Tags: differential-geometry

Given geodesic curvature and torsion $\kappa_g,\tau_g$ on a surface as functions of arc,  how to compute (stand alone $\mathbb R^3 $embedded )  curvature and torsion $\kappa,\tau $?

Are the following correct/relevant in this context ?  I did not see them in printed on same page of any text. $\gamma$ is angle between total vector and normal.

EDIT 1 (typo):

$\kappa_n = \kappa  \cos \gamma $ ( Meusnier thm )

same as

$\kappa_g = \kappa_n  \tan \gamma $ ( also Meusnier thm )

and

$\tau_g = \tau + \dfrac{d \gamma}{ds} $ (Joachimsthal thm?)